# XPath query to match depending on combinations of child elements

Tags: xpath, matching

Given the following XML Snippet

```
 <Events>
    <Event>
     <DateTime>22.09.2009 11:27:18</DateTime>
     <EventType>Download</EventType>
 </Event>
```

What is the XPath query to return all Events created today of type download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/Events/Event[starts-with(DateTime, '22.09.2009') and EventType='Download']
```

Since I assume that this is a follow-up to your previous question, you might want to use this snippet instead of SelectSingleNode to get all events in a file (if there can be multiple):

```
foreach (XPathNavigator node in doc.CreateNavigator().Select(expression)) {
    // matching node found in document; will process all matching nodes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Events/Event[contains(DateTime,'22.09.2009') and EventType='Download']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/Events/Event[substring(DateTime, 0, 10)='22.09.2009' and EventType='Download']
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how a regular expression would help in finding today's date?