# XPath query to match depending on combinations of child elements

Tags: xpath, matching

I have the following Xml structure; Payment/Line which has amongst its element a IsFeePayment and a IsServiceProduct elements of type bool.

```
<Payment>
   <Line>
      <IsFeePayment>true</IsFeePayment>
       <ISServiceProduct>true</IsServiceProduct>    
   </Line>
 </Payment>
```

i want an xpath statement that returns 'true' when both of these are are they are, true.
if either one is false, i want the xpath statement to return 'false'

THe xpath below is almost there, it returns the line when both are true.

/*[local-name()='Payment']/*[local-name()='Line'][*[local-name()='IsFeePayment'][text()='true'] and *[local-name()='IsServiceProduct'][text()='true']]

how do i just get a simple bool out instead of the whole element?

Comment: essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460028/xpath-query-to-match-depending-on-combinations-of-child-elements

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the xpath to

```
boolean(//Payment/Line[IsFeePayment='true' and IsServiceProduct='true'])
```

Answer (score 0):

simply adding a boolean() around the xpath expression i already had fixes the problem *blush*

so ...

boolean(/*[local-name()='Payment']/*[local-name()='Line'][*[local-name()='IsFeePayment'][text()='true'] and *[local-name()='IsServiceProduct'][text()='true']])